# Insert record into two Oracle tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, oracle

[image: This is First table of database and it is in relation with second table]

[image: This is the Second Table]

We have a questions, that user have to answer. So what I need is: after user logs on into the site, he answers to the questions and this answer should be saved into database. So every user will answer the question and it have to be saved in a database. (Second table has corresponding USERID column).

Comment: This answer should be closed.  Not only is your question impossible to understand, you can't even be bothered to type in 9 field names and their types so it is readable.  To make a question understandable... give examples with real data and expected results -- and bother to type it into the question so it is readable.

Comment: @Hogan I tried to edit the question in a understandable way. It was really difficult to understand...

Comment: @FarjadAhmad what does your "OverDressed" column means?

Comment: @Khazratbek - Saw your edit -- your edit creates a question with no question.  What is the question?

Comment: @Hogan Have you saw "So what I need is" or no? I think it is enough to be considered as a question. Anyway, it is not my question, so I just tried to improve his idea to be understand by others.

Comment: Question is how to work with foriegn key in user detail table

Comment: Overdressed is a question

Comment: @FarjadAhmad  Overdressed is not a question -- overdressed is a word. --  "How to work with foreign key in a table is not a question.  Using foreign keys is well covered in any tutorial site or text book.  If you try to solve this problem in a specific way and it is not working then you can post the code you have and say how it is not work.  The question "How to work with foriegn (sp) key?"  Is just to broad for this website.

Comment: @Khazratbek - A "Show me the codez" or as you put it "So what I need is" question is not acceptable on this website.  This is not a website for open ended software consulting.  There are websites for that.  This website is for solving exact questions about programming.  In the help you can find many good descriptions on how to ask a good question.  Questions are typically answered in a few minutes.  This question has been here for hours.  It won't be answered unless it is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

The easy answer is: TWO connections :)

I would load and cache your people table as long as it does not contain more than around 3-4000 people. If there are more, then you will have memory issues.

With this table loaded in a simple List you can then do selections from the OTHER database to find out if they're overdressing :)

Comment: Instead of two connections, he would rather use one dataset with a two datatables. I may be mistaken, but I think you misunderstood his question...

Comment: Yup, I probably misunderstood as well - I somehow managed to read into it that there were two different databases. Sorry about that